# regarding search hard key behaviour with progress bar (android)

Tags: android

When a progress dialog is displaying and we press search hard key it closes and moves to search bar of phone, even if if the progress Dialog setcancellable value is set false.

how can we avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this){
    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to avoid this. You can not forbid the user to leave your app. He will always be able to press the home key to go back and send your Application in the background. If you have a running notcancelable dialog the user will get back to this activity at the moment he reenters your app. You have to build your app in a way that it will work even if the app is send to the background and revisited later.

Comment: i agree with u.
but my problem is diffrent.
in android 2.1 on search key press user is moved out of app and when user comes to my app(by pressing home long button as you said) the non cancelable progress dialog does not get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and fixed it by setting an `OnKeyListener` on the progress dialog that consumes the search button press:

```
    dlg.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

That did the trick for me.